# APC Cache 99% Misses

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

I have installed APC Cache, and i see that there is only 1 Hit and 78 Misses.

```
Cached Files    78 ( 5.7 MBytes)
Hits    1
Misses  78

apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    32
```

Am I doing something wrong? I have just installed it via PECL and added the extension in my php.ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've just installed it, then the content won't be in the cache unless the same content has been requested a second time.

Comment: i do understand that, but it's been already requested 1000 times since i wrote this question

Comment: Ah, then you should update your question to provide this valuable detail.